# How to merge common strings with different values between parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, nlp, substring, lcs

I am processing some strings within lists that look like these:

`['COLOR INCLUDES (40)', 'LONG_DESCRIPTION CONTAINS ("BLACK")', 'COLOR INCLUDES (38)']`

`['COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839)', 'COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,409,800,823,830,833,838,839)', 'COLOR INCLUDES (800)']`

Thing is, I want to merge similar strings with their values into one, for each list. Expecting something like this:

`['COLOR INCLUDES (40,38)', 'LONG_DESCRIPTION CONTAINS ("BLACK")']`

`['COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,409,800,823,830,833,838,839)']`

And some strings may have values without ():

`['FAMILY EQUALS 1145']`

What could be the more pythonic and fastest (lazy :P) way of doing this?

I have tried using regex to match strings until a "(" appears, but some strings don't have values between (), and can't find a fitting solution.

I have also tried STree function from suffix_trees lib, which finds the LCS (Longest Common Subsequence) from a list of strings, but then ran out of ideas about handling the values and the closing parenthesis:

```
from suffix_trees import STree
st = STree.STree(['COLOR INCLUDES(30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839)', 
'COLOR INCLUDES(30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,409,800,823,830,833,838,839)', 'COLOR INCLUDES (800)'])
st.lcs()

out: 'COLOR INCLUDES ('
```

EDIT: SOLVED

As @stef in the answer said, I broke the problem in smaller pieces and I solved it with his help. Let me paste here the **Class Rule_process** and the result:

```py
class Rule_process:

    def __init__(self):
        self.rules = '(COLOR INCLUDES (40)) OR (LONG_DESCRIPTION CONTAINS ("BLACK")):1|||COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839):0|||COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,409,800,823,830,833,838,839):0|||COLOR INCLUDES (40):1|||COLOR INCLUDES (800):0'
        
        self.rules_dict = {
            0:None,
            1:None,
            2:None,
            4:None,
        }
     
    def append_rules(self):

        rules = self.rules.split("|||")

        values_0 = []
        values_1 = []
        values_2 = []
        values_4 = []

        for rule in range(len(rules)):

            if rules[rule][-1]=='0':
                rules[rule] = rules[rule][:-2]
                # self.rules_dict[0].append(rules[rule])
                values_0.append(rules[rule])

            elif rules[rule][-1]=='1':
                rules[rule] = rules[rule][:-2]
                # self.rules_dict[1].append(rules[rule])
                values_1.append(rules[rule])

            elif rules[rule][-1]=='2':
                rules[rule] = rules[rule][:-2]
                # self.rules_dict[2].append(rules[rule])
                values_2.append(rules[rule])

            elif rules[rule][-1]=='4':
                rules[rule] = rules[rule][:-2]
                # self.rules_dict[4].append(rules[rule])
                values_4.append(rules[rule])

        if values_0!=[]:
            self.rules_dict[0] = values_0
        if values_1!=[]:
            self.rules_dict[1] = values_1
        if values_2!=[]:
            self.rules_dict[2] = values_2
        if values_4!=[]:
            self.rules_dict[4] = values_4
        
        regex = r'^\('

        # for rules in self.rules_dict.values():
        for key in self.rules_dict.keys():

            if self.rules_dict[key] is not None:
                for rule in range(len(self.rules_dict[key])):
                    
                    new_rule = self.rules_dict[key][rule].split(' OR ')

                    if len(new_rule)>1:
                        joined_rule = []
                        for r in new_rule:
                            r = r.replace("))",")")
                            r = re.sub(regex, "", r)
                            joined_rule.append(r)
                        
                        self.rules_dict[key].remove(self.rules_dict[key][rule])
                        self.rules_dict[key].extend(joined_rule)
                        self.rules_dict[key] = list(set(self.rules_dict[key]))

                    else:
                        new_rule = [r.replace("))",")") for r in new_rule]
                        new_rule = [re.sub(regex, "", r) for r in new_rule]
                    
                        new_rule = ", ".join(new_rule)

                        self.rules_dict[key][rule] = new_rule
                        self.rules_dict[key] = list(set(self.rules_dict[key]))

        return self.rules_dict

    
    def split_rule(self):   # COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33) -> name = 'COLOR INCLUDES', values = [30,31,32,33]
                            # LONG_DESCRIPTION CONTAINS ("BLACK") -> name = LONG_DESCRIPTION, values ='"BLACK"'
        
        new_dict = {
            0:None,
            1:None,
            2:None,
            4:None,
        }
        
        for key in self.rules_dict.keys():

            pql_dict = {}

            if self.rules_dict[key] is not None:
                for rule in range(len(self.rules_dict[key])): #self.rules_dict[key][rule] -> COLOR INCLUDES (30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839)

                    rule = self.rules_dict[key][rule]

                    name = rule.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0]  #------------------------------->COLOR INCLUDES
                    values_as_str = rule.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[1].replace("(","")
                    values_as_str = values_as_str.replace(")","") #-------------------------------> 30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839
                    
                    try:
                        values = list(map(int, values_as_str.split(","))) # [30,31,32,33,56,74,84,85,93,99,184,800,823,830,833,838,839]
                    except:
                        values = values_as_str # '"BLACK"'
            
                    if name in pql_dict.keys():
                        pql_dict[name] = pql_dict[name] + (values)
                        pql_dict[name] = list(set(pql_dict[name])) 
                        
                    else:
                        pql_dict.setdefault(name, values)

            # pql_dict = {'COLOR INCLUDES': [32, 33, 800, 99, 833, 838, 839, 74, 84, 85, 30, 823, 184, 409, 56, 93, 830, 31]}
                for name in pql_dict.keys():
                    
                    values = pql_dict[name]
                    joined_rule = name + " " + str(values)
                    
                    if new_dict[key] is not None:
                        new_dict[key] = new_dict[key] + [joined_rule]
                    else:
                        new_dict[key] = [joined_rule]
                   
        self.rules_dict = new_dict
```

And the result:

```py
process = Rule_process()
process.append_rules()
process.split_rule()
process.rules_dict

OUT:

{0: ['COLOR INCLUDES [32, 33, 800, 99, 833, 838, 839, 74, 84, 85, 30, 823, 184, 409, 56, 93, 830, 31]'],
 1: ['COLOR INCLUDES [40]', 'LONG_DESCRIPTION CONTAINS "BLACK"'],
 2: None,
 4: None}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried; someone might be able to help fix it.

Comment: Split this task into smaller, simpler tasks. First task: write a function that takes a string and returns a pair `(name, list_of_values)` where `name` is the first part of the string and `list_of_values` is a python list of integers.

Comment: Second task: write a function that takes a list of pairs `(name, list_of_values)` and merges the lists when the names are equal. This is extremely easy in python using a dict with `name` as key and `list_of_values` as value.

Comment: Third task: Write a function to convert back, from the pairs `(name, list_of_values)` to the strings `"name (value1, value2, ...)"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split this task into smaller, simpler tasks.

##### First task:

Write a function that takes a string and returns a pair `(name, list_of_values)` where `name` is the first part of the string and `list_of_values` is a python list of integers.

Hint: You can use `'(' in s` to test whether string `s` contains an opening parenthesis; you can use `s.split()` to split on whitespace or `s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)` to only split on the last whitespace; `s.split('(')` to split on opening parenthesis; and `s.split(',')` to split on comma.

##### Second task:

Write a function that takes a list of pairs `(name, list_of_values)` and merges the lists when the names are equal.

Hint: This is extremely easy in python using a dict with `name` as key and `list_of_values` as value. You can use `if name in d: ... else:` to test whether a name is already in the dict or not; or you can use `d.get(name, [])` or `d.setdefault(name, [])` to automatically add a `name: []` entry in the dict when `name` is not already in the dict.

##### Third task:

Write a function to convert back, from the pairs `(name, list_of_values)` to the strings `"name (value1, value2, ...)"`. This task is easier than the first task, so I suggest doing it first.

Hint: `' '.join(...)` and `','.join(...)` can both be useful.

Comment: Yep, that kind of approach could work, as I have done a lot of preprocessing with small functions before getting to that list of strings. Gonna try it now! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Got third task now, and second is mostly as your hint. But the problem with the first task is that some rules may not contain parenthesis and contain the value after the "name" part. 

Guess I could use a dict with all the "names" that can appear (I know how to look for these "names") and check if string contains any of the dict values

Comment: @LuisGT Just test whether there is a parenthesis in the string or not, and handle the two cases differently. `if '(' in s: ... else: name, number_as_str = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1); list_of_values = [ int(number_as_str) ]`